# Is every order type of a PA model the \omega of some ZFC model?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Let $N$ be a model of first-order Peano arithmetic, and let $\sigma$ be its order-type. Does it follow that there is a (non-transitive, expect when $M$ is the standard model) $ZFC$-model $M$ such that $\omega^{M}=\sigma$? What if $PA$ is strengthened to true arithmetic (i.e. the theory of $(\mathbb{N},+,\cdot)$ or weakened to a subtheory such as $I\Sigma_{1}$, $I\Delta_{0}+EXP$, $I\Delta_{0}$ or $IOpen$? Or when we replace $ZFC$ with something weaker like $KP$?

Answer (score 13):

For countable models, the answer is yes, since all nonstandard such models have the same order type. (For the standard model $N=\mathbb{N}$, assume there is an $\omega$-standard model of ZFC, and in general we must assume Con(ZFC).) Namely, if $N\models\text{PA}$ is nonstandard, then its order type is $\omega+\mathbb{Z}\cdot\mathbb{Q}$, and this is also the order type appearing as the $\omega$ of any $\omega$-nonstandard countable model of ZFC.

It seems to me that this argument would also work for saturated models in larger cardinalities, but I'm unsure of the general case.

A related question would be: which models of PA arise as the full standard structure of arithmetic $\langle\mathbb{N},+,\cdot,0,1,<\rangle^M$ of a model $M\models\text{ZFC}$? In other words, we ask for the full structure, rather than merely the order type as you have. These are known as the ZFC-standard models of PA, and in the countable case they are exactly the standard model of PA (provided there is an $\omega$-model of ZFC), together with the computably saturated models of the arithmetic consequences of ZFC, a theory denoted $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N})^{\text{ZFC}}$. For a discussion of this and applications, see proposition 3 of [Satisfaction is not absolute](http://jdh.hamkins.org/satisfaction-is-not-absolute/), as well as a 2009 report of Ali Enayat on the topic for the Mittlag-Lefflar institute.

Meanwhile, I was able to get the following, which works even for
uncountable models. (**Update:** I made this an equivalence.)

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent for any $N\models\text{PA}$.

1. For any finitely many axioms $\varphi_0,\ldots,\varphi_n$ of ZFC, the model $N$ thinks they are consistent.
2. As a model of arithmetic, $N$ is isomorphic to an initial segment
   of the standard model $\mathbb{N}^M$ of some $M\models\text{ZFC}$.
3. $N$ satisfies all the $\Pi_1^0$ consequences of ZFC.

Proof. ($2\to 3$) If $N$ is an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}^M$ for some $M\models\text{ZFC}$, then $N$ must satisfy all the $\Pi_1^0$ arithmetic statements true in $M$.

($3\to 1$) Those consistency statements are amongst the $\Pi_1^0$ consequences of ZFC, which proves the consistency of any particular of its finite fragments.

($1\to 2$) Suppose that $N$ is a model of PA in
which every standard finite fragment of standard ZFC is consistent. (This
follows from $N\models\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$, but it is a strictly
weaker hypothesis.) In particular, this hypothesis implies that ZFC is consistent, and so we may assume without loss that $N$ is nonstandard. Consider $N$'s version of the theory ZFC. We
may enumerate what it thinks are the axioms, which of course
includes many nonstandard axioms. Since we have assumed that $N$
thinks all the standard-finite initial segments of this
enumeration are consistent, by overspill there is some nonstandard
finite theory $t$ in $N$ which $N$ thinks is consistent, and which
includes every standard axiom of ZFC.

Inside $N$, we may now build the usual Henkin completion $T$ of
$t$. That is, we add Henkin constants and add every sentence
$\sigma$ or its negation $\neg\sigma$ in the new language, in such
a way that $N$ thinks $T$ extends $t$ and remains consistent,
while having the Henkin property. The theory $T$ is a definable
class in $N$, and $N$ is also able to define the corresponding
Henkin model $M$.

By meta-theoretic induction, we can show that $M\models\sigma$
just in case $\sigma\in T$, for every standard finite sentence
$\sigma$ in the expanded language. In particular, it follows that
$M$ is a model of ZFC.

Finally, I claim that $N$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of
the $\mathbb{N}^M$, and indeed, $N$ is able to construct this
isomorphism. For every $a\in N$, the model $N$ is able to
construct the term $\overbrace{1+\cdots+1}^a$, and it has added a
Henkin constant $\hat a$ and the assertion $\hat
a=\overbrace{1+\cdots+1}^a$ to the theory $T$. Furthermore, $N$
believes that it is able to prove (by induction) that $x<\hat a$
implies $x=\hat b$ for some $b<a$. It also must believe things
like $\hat{(a+b)}=\hat a+\hat b$ and $\hat{(a\cdot b)}=\hat
a\cdot\hat b$, since these kind of manipulations of terms are
provable in PA. Thus, the map $$a\mapsto (\hat a)^M$$ is an
isomorphism of $\langle N,+,\cdot,0,1,<\rangle$ to an initial
segment of $\mathbb{N}^M$, as desired. QED

**Corollary.** If ZFC is consistent, then every model of true arithmetic, and indeed every model of $\text{PA}+\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$, arises as an initial segment of the standard model $\mathbb{N}^M$ of some model $M\models\text{ZFC}$ of set theory.

One can replace ZFC in this argument with other set theories, such as KP or ZFC + large cardinals, and get an equivalence for other theories.

Basically, in the implication ($1\to 2$) of the theorem, the model $N$ thinks it
has constructed an $\omega$-nonstandard model of the theory $t$,
and it naturally believes that what it thinks is the standard
model, itself, is an initial segment of that model.

Comment: Joel: thanks for the reference to my 2009 report.  A revised draft of that report now appears in the following volume, on pages 55-64: http://flov.gu.se/digitalAssets/1497/1497175_ideesfixes.pdf

Comment: Great! I was hoping you'd come through with a link.

Comment: Joel: your theorem remains true with $PA$ weakened to $I\Sigma_1$ because is known that the arithmetized completeness theorem can be implemented in $I\Sigma_1$ (this is a nontrivial result, the first proof of it was given by a forcing argument of Harrington that shows that every countable model of $I\Sigma_1$ has an expansion to a model of $WKL_0$).  Also, in the theorem, one can replace $ZFC$ with any of its r.e. extensions (indeed, with any r.e. extension of a very weak fragment of $ZF$, a fragment that proves that $(\omega, \in)$ is a discrete linear order).

Answer (score 10):

Joel Hamkins has already answered the question in the positive for countable models of PA; indeed PA can be relaxed to IOpen in his argument.

**In the uncountable case, as far as I know, the problem is wide open.**

My reason: a closely related question is still (wide) open, namely, *is it possible to have distinct consistent completions $T_1$ and $T_2$ of PA such that the collection of order-types of uncountable models of $T_1$ differs from the collection of order-types of uncountable models of $T_2$ ?*

This open question was first brought to world attention by Harvey Friedman in his 1975-paper "One hundred and two problems in mathematical logic" (in Journal of Symbolic Logic).

For the state of the art (in relation to order-types of models of PA) see Chapter 11 of the [Kossak-Schmerl graduate text on on models of arithmetic](http://sistemas.fciencias.unam.mx/~lokylog/images/stories/Alexandria/Oxford%20Logic%20Guides/%5BOLG%2050%5D%20The%20Structure%20of%20Models%20of%20Peano%20Arithmetic%20-%20Roman%20Kossak,%20James%20Schmerl%20%5BOxford%20Logic%20Guides%5D%20(2006)(T).pdf).  Friedman's problem is mentioned there both in Chapter 11, and also in Chapter 12 (List of 20 open questions).